# How to set a different "n" value than data frame length for prop.table (or a similar proportion/percentage table function)?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, tidyverse, percentage

I have a dataframe of length 3000 with different occupations of 2500 different people (many respondents have multiple jobs). There is no ID var, it is just 1 column (Occupation) with the list of occupations (e.g., lobbyist, teacher, teacher, lobbyist, government employee, etc.).

I would like to see what percentage of my n=2500 each occupation is. So, as many people have multiple jobs, all of the percentages should add up to over 100%.

Here is the prop table I created, however, it bases the calculations off of n=3000. Is there a way to set the prop.table to n=2500? If not, is there another function I should use?

This is my code:

```
# Create the Proportion table 
Occupation_Perc <- t(prop.table(table(NewData$Occupation))) #* 100  

# filter out uncommon occupations (I'm only interested in common ones)

Occupation_Perc <- data.frame(Occupation_Perc)  %>%
  filter(Freq > .01)

# Drop unnecessary column produced by prop.table, and rename other column
Occupation_Perc <- as.data.frame(Occupation_Perc) %>%
  select(-Var1) %>%
  rename(Occupation = Var2)
```

Comment: `prop.table` does not have any such options, but if you share a few rows of sample input and explain your desired output we can help out.